# Calculate the time remaining until a subscription

Tags: php, math

I have a subscription that can be subscribed to every month, every two months or every 3 months. That's represented as a `subscription_frequency` of 1, 2 or 3.

I then have a `month_joined` property (1 through 12).

But I'm trying to work out, when someone should receive their subscription. So far I know I want to work out when the user will next receive a subscription.

<sup>[disclaimer: I get mixed up between modulo and remainder when in php]</sup>

So I'm adding 12 to the current month, then subtracting the `month_joined` number, and then finding the remainder of their `subscription_frequency`, to add on to the current month to tell them when their next box is due.

```
public function nextsub()
{
    $remainder = ($current_month + 12 - $this->month_joined) % $this->subscription_frequency;
    return $current_month + remainder;
}
```

But all my number are coming out screwy. Here is dump of users:

```
[
{
current_month: 3,
month_joined: 1,
subscription_frequency: 1,
next_box: 3
},
{
current_month: 3,
month_joined: 3,
subscription_frequency: 3,
next_box: 3
},
{
current_month: 3,
month_joined: 11,
subscription_frequency: 3,
next_box: 4<----------------- this is incorrect
},
{
current_month: 3,
month_joined: 12,
subscription_frequency: 3,
next_box: 3<----------------- this is incorrect
},
{
current_month: 3,
month_joined: 8,
subscription_frequency: 2,
next_box: 4
},
{
current_month: 3,
month_joined: 1,
subscription_frequency: 1,
next_box: 3
},
{
current_month: 3,
month_joined: 3,
subscription_frequency: 2,
next_box: 3
},
{
current_month: 3,
month_joined: 2,
subscription_frequency: 3,
next_box: 4 <----------------- this is incorrect
},
{
current_month: 3,
month_joined: 2,
subscription_frequency: 1,
next_box: 3
}
]
```

What's the matter with my maths?

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: Because my code works but the concept doesn't... am I wrong to post it here?

Comment: Any time I see date arithmetic like this it makes me nervous. I am not familiar with PHP's date functionality any more (been ten years or so) but I would recommend reading up on that topic. There most likely is a better way of doing this, but I unfortunately do not know what that way might be exactly.

Comment: If your numbers are coming out screwy, your code doesn't work.  Stack Overflow isn't just about compile errors and typos, and we don't do code troubleshooting here.

Comment: Ha.. oh well... I'm yet to find a decent question for you guys. I'll close this question and head over there!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this ...

```
$next_box = ($current_month + ($month_joined % $subscription_frequency + $current_month % subscription_frequency)) % 12;
```

so if its March your frequency was 3 and you joined in November

```
(3 + (11 % 3 + 3 % 3)) % 12 = 5
```

next box comes in May